# How to read user input without pressing ENTER?

Tags: c

I'm writing code where I need to get input without the user pressing ENTER.
The code is basically that I need to get 4 numbers from 1-6 without the user pressing ENTER all in one line.

I tried doing so with `getchar()`, but it doesn't work.

How do I do that?

Here's that part of the code:

```
int p1 = 0;
int p2 = 0;
int p3 = 0;
int p4 = 0;
p1 = getchar() - 48;
p2 = getchar() - 48;
p3 = getchar() - 48;
p4 = getchar() - 48;
```

Comment: There is no standard function for this. You will have to use something OS-specific. Note that the [original designers of C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Thompson#/media/File:Ken_Thompson_(sitting)_and_Dennis_Ritchie_at_PDP-11_(2876612463).jpg) used a separate terminal that didn't send anything to the computer until you pressed Enter.

Comment: Enter them all on one line, without spaces, and press <Enter> once. For example `1234<Enter>`. Aside: please replace the "magic number" `48` with `'0'`.

Comment: In MSVC you can use `_getch()` or `_getche()`.

Comment: How about getting input as a string line, split and convert it to integer ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a C FAQ: [12.5 How can I read one character at a time, without waiting for the RETURN key](http://c-faq.com/stdio/index.html)?

To quote:

Depending on which operating system you're using and what libraries you have available, you may be able to use one (or more!) of the following techniques:

- If you can use the **curses** library, you can call cbreak [footnote] (and perhaps noecho), after which calls to getch will return characters immediately.
- If all you're trying to do is read a short password without echo, you may be able to use a function called getpass, if it's available. (Another possibility for hiding typed passwords is to select black characters on a black background.)
- Under *classic* versions of Unix, use ioctl and the TIOCGETP and TIOCSETP (or TIOCSETN) requests on file descriptor 0 to manipulate the sgttyb structure, defined in <sgtty.h> and documented in tty(4). In the sg_flags field, set the CBREAK (or RAW) bit, and perhaps clear the ECHO bit.
- Under System V Unix, use ioctl and the TCGETAW and TCSETAW requests on file descriptor 0 to manipulate the termio structure, defined in <termio.h>. In the c_lflag field, clear the ICANON (and perhaps ECHO) bits. Also, set c_cc[VMIN] to 1 and c_cc[VTIME] to 0.
- Under any operating system (Unix or otherwise) offering POSIX compatibility, use the tcgetattr and tcsetattr calls on file descriptor 0 to manipulate the termios structure, defined in <termios.h>. In the c_lflag field, clear the ICANON (and perhaps ECHO) bits. Also, set c_cc[VMIN] to 1 and c_cc[VTIME] to 0.
- In a pinch, under Unix, use system (see [question 19.27](http://c-faq.com/osdep/system.html)) to invoke the stty command to set terminal driver modes (as in the preceding three items).
- Under MS-DOS, use getch or getche, or the corresponding BIOS interrupts.
- Under VMS, try the Screen Management (SMG$) routines, or curses, or issue low-level $QIO's with the IO$_READVBLK function code (and perhaps IO$M_NOECHO, and others) to ask for one character at a time. (It's also possible to set character-at-a-time or ``pass through'' modes in the VMS terminal driver.)
- Under other operating systems, you're on your own.

Answer (score 0):

> There is no standard function for this.

There are some custom solutions e.g. [https://www.cs.uleth.ca/~holzmann/C/system/ttyraw.c](https://www.cs.uleth.ca/%7Eholzmann/C/system/ttyraw.c) But your mileage may vary.

However if this kind of dynamic use of the terminal is core to your program I would recommend using ncurses or something similar.